# PDF form export with QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, pdf, workflow

First: I am complete newbie to GIS.

I try to find a workflow for my upcoming project that involves a lot GPS data and recurring activities.

Short explanation: I am doing inspections for certain geographical areas and document findings using GPS based location. Since this a goverment matter in my country i have to create reports for them regularly. **These reports must be printed and a template is already given**. The information that has to be filled is very detailed but on the other hand also very easy to find online or are just recurring personal information. For me this is a perfect candidate of a computer aided task, since a lot of APIs can be used ... like finding the corresponding city that is related to the finding, which time the GPS data was recorded and other local info that is relevant ... but doing this even for a few findings manually usually takes my whole sunday

My idea is the following:

Get the gpx files from the GPS tracker and import them as shapefiles to QGIS. Enrich the feature attributes table with data from WFS and export them by having some kind of "Report button" where I can choose the desired period of time to create a report for. Since personal info is involed, that is for every report the same, I also have to save this info somewhere and put it on the PDF file.

I know, there is no out of the box solution. But I found already the most of the parts that makes it "possible" (GPX import, WFS integration, data aggregation etc.). But I did not found something for export for example attribute tables to a form based PDF that is print ready.

Is there something like this that is supported by QGIS? When not, any other suggestions? How is something like this done usually? Since I am professional programmer I am also not afraid programming it as a kind of "Plugin" to QGIS if its possible. Any chance for that?

Comment: I suggest you make yourself familiar with the layout manager.

Comment: If this might solve my issue (?) I only know that this capable to "compose" the element to a page ... but PDF forms? Any links for more info?

Comment: You're aware of the QGIS documentation?

Comment: Didn't deep dive, but does not seem to be capable of handling PDFs that has given forms to be filled with data .. thats why i asked for here

Comment: Maybe you should make a bit more clear, that you already have a PDF file where fields need to be filled out.

Comment: _These reports must be printed and a template is already given._ ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ ... anyway, made it bold